# After replacing hard drive in HP ProBook 4530s it doesn't boot or let me go to BIOS, it always goes to system diagnostics

Tags: ssd, hp-laptop

If I attempt to boot with a "newly replaced" hard drive in my laptop (replaced original HDD with newer SSD), it says "no operating system found, hit <kbd>F2</kbd> to run diagnostics"

If I hit <kbd>F2</kbd>, it is able to run various diagnostics including HDD diagnostic. And reboot.

If I hit any key while booting to enter BIOS setup (<kbd>F10</kbd> or <kbd>F9</kbd> to change boot order), it just takes me to "system diagnostics" I can never enter the BIOS at all. How do I use a new drive in this laptop?

Basically a dupe of [this](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebooks-Archive-Read-Only/When-I-try-to-access-BIOS-Setup-System-diagnostics-appear/td-p/5089761) question on HP's site, but I didn't find the answer there and cannot leave a new answer.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed if I proceeded to plug in a Windows install media into the USB, it would actually boot to the install media.  And also I would suddenly be able to get into the BIOS.  Very weird.

At install time, Windows complained "cannot install on selected partition The Selected Disk is of the GPT Partition Style" which [means](https://www.diskgenius.com/how-to/the-selected-disk-is-of-the-gpt-partition-style.php) the BIOS was "older" MBR and drive was "newer" EFI. And possibly was a clue.

After enabling EFI in the BIOS (it said "experimental, not supported" and didn't seem enabled by default), now I can access BIOS with that new drive installed like normal.

Hunch is that formatting the drive back to MBR would have worked also.

Apparently if the HP BIOS doesn't detect a drive it understands, it doesn't even let you enter BIOS, weird. Updating BIOS might have helped but doubtful.